# How to enable Wireless Network

Tags: wireless, bluetooth

How to enable bluetooth & wifi on my HP nx 6120 laptop. Please give me instructions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if your network icon, is not on the up right corner;
you can go to the up right corner of your desktop page and right click, then in then choose:

system setting> network> wireless

and you can find the name of your wifi connection. then click on it and write your password.

You are connected.
Done!

Answer (score 0):

**GUI METHOD**

In the right upper corner you should see a networking indicator. Click on it to show drop-down menu, and check-mark "Enable Networking" and "Enable wifi". 
Similar thing goes for bluetooth - you should have an indicator in the rught upper corner.

You also may want to have it start on boot. For that open Unity Dash ( the square with ubuntu logo in the left upper corner ) and search for Startup Applications. Once you found that, check-mark bluetooth.

You can also do it in System Settings-> Bluetooth and System Settings-> Network

**COMMAND LINE METHODS**
These methods are for command line (gnome terminal, which can be opened in Ctrl+Alt+T)

To start network manager: `sudo service network-manager start`

To start wifi : `nmcli nm wifi on`

To start bluetooth: `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth start`

Comment: let us know, if none of these methods help. You may have issues with wireless card or something